# Behavior of nested finally in Exceptions

Tags: java

Today at work, I had to review a code snippet that looks similar to this mock example.

`package test;`

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class ExceptionTester {

    public static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ExceptionTester.class);

public void test() throws IOException {
    new IOException();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ExceptionTester comparator = new ExceptionTester();
    try {
        try {
            comparator.test();
        } finally {
            System.out.println("Finally 1");
        }
    } catch(IOException ex) {
        logger.error("Exception happened" ex);
            // also close opened resources
    } 
    System.out.println("Exiting out of the program");
}
```

}

It's printing the following output.I expected an compile error since the inner `try` did not have a `catch` block.

```
Finally 1
Exiting out of the program
```

I do not understand why `IOException` is caught by the outer `catch` block. I would appreciate if anyone can explain this, especially by citing stack unwinding process

Comment: A `try` must have >=1 `catch` __and/or__ a `finally`.  The `catch` is not required.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A finally block represents a task that has to be done under both normal and abnormal conditions.

Example: You take an interview candidate to lunch.  While at lunch, you find out he's wanted by the police for murder.  Exception!  Lunch is over, the interview is a total loss, but... you still have to pay for lunch.

```
try {
    meetForLunch(interviewCandidate);
}
finally {
    lunchBill.pay();
}
```

Note that paying for lunch hasn't taken care of the exception, you've still got to do something about the murderer at your interview.  It's just a loose end that has to be taken care of before processing with damage control.

Most finally blocks are used in that way: A file needs to be closed whether you successfully saved the data or not, a database connection needs to be closed whether the transaction was approved or not, etc.

And the exception continues outward on its merry way, looking for a matching catch block in an enclosing scope.

Note that finally blocks will always run *unless* the process ends while the try block is still executing.

Comment: Of course, this analogy breaks down if the candidate murders you at lunch.  :-)

Comment: @Stephen: I think you missed the last sentence.

Comment: @Ben Voight - as far as the restaurant is concerned, the process has not ended.

Comment: @Stephen: The restaurant is just going to have to initiate recovery procedures.

Comment: @Ben - the real problem is that `lunchBill.pay()` needs a different implementation if you are dead.

Comment: @Stephen: If you're dead, the finally block won't run.  The restaurant then has to detect the lost connection with its client and, as I commented, initiate recovery proceedings (against the murderer, or the estate, or the employer since it was a business trip).  In the programming world, databases have to deal with abandoned transactions when the client process dies.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that your function

```
public void test() throws IOException {
    new IOException();
}
```

Doesn't actually throw an exception - it just creates a new IOException() object.  Changing this to

```
public void test() throws IOException {
    throw new IOException();
}
```

should fix this.

Comment: That's why "exception happened" wasn't printed, but it has no bearing on the `finally` block.

Answer (score 0):

The code above **does not require much** of an explanation - not definitely involving call stacks!. What is your confusion?did I miss something?
Here is my explanation

First point

- You don't need both a catch and a
  finally block. You can have one of
  them or both of them with a
  try-block, but not none of them.
- The code inside the finally clause
  will always be executed, even if an
  exception is thrown from within the
  try or catch block. If your code has
  a return statement inside the try or
  catch block, the code inside the
  finally-block will get executed
  before returning from the method.

So in the above code, an exception was never thrown (because you are not using `throw` in the `test()` method)
However, `finally` block got executed as promised by the the language spec and you got the output `Finally 1`. The next statement in the sequence of execution is the `System.out.println("Exiting out of the program");` as the `catch` block never reached as there are no IOExceptions. So, `Exiting out of the program` is printed.